# HSQLDB in resources within a WAR

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, properties, hsqldb

I've developed a small application using Spring Boot, which uses HSQLDB as a database to store users, for the time being. What I want to do is store the database within Maven's resource folder. My application.properties file contains the following configuration:

```
#...
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/database/dashboard
#...
```

So, whenever I start the application with Java (right click on my Application's main() and Run As Spring Boot App), the database is stored right.

But, after packaging a WAR file with `mvn clean install spring-boot:repackage`, deploying it into Tomcat, e.g., and running it, the database is not stored within the exploded WAR.

My question is how can I tell `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:*` property to store the database within Maven Resources directory (which will point still after exploding the WAR)? Could I use some sort of environment variable as used in pom.xml?

**EDIT**
Given the answers by @Steve C and @fredt, I've realised that the database shouldn't be stored within the war. Instead, I'll store it within the user's Home dir `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:~/tomcat_webapp_data/dashboard/database`.. Thank you so much!

Comment: you seem to be using a relative path to point to hsqldb. Hsql's file location will be relative to the working dir (probably bin/ in tomcat/ ) . You should use a absolute path.

Comment: 1) Better use Apache Derby, HSQLDB is always entirely loaded into RAM memory - this could kill your app with bigger DB 2) just change the build script to include the entire db directory iinto war, then be sure to have proper path to db file in server container

Comment: @Redlab I don't want to use an absolute path, since I don't know the nature of the system where the WAR will be placed (linux, win...) nor whether it'll be run with java.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki I feel that I'd be having the same issue using Derby... The database will be really small. Your second approach seems right. But if I initialise the DB and include it in the war, the configuration of the datasource will still be needed (the reference to a relative path).

Answer (score 2):

The directories and contents of a WAR file are read-only.

You can set the read_only flag in the HSQLDB database .properties file before including in the WAR. You access this kind of database with a `jdbc:hsqldb:res:<path>` URL.

If you want to store data in a persistent and updatable database, connect to the (at first non-existent) database within your application and set up its tables if they don't yet exist with data from a resource. You can then store data. The database path should be outside the directories that are used for jars and resources.

Contrary to one of the comments, HSQLDB is not limited to storing data in memory and can have disk-based tables, called CACHED tables.

You can include a variable in the database URL to pick up a pre-defined property from the web server. For example:

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:${mydbpath}
```

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html#dpc_variables_url

Answer (score 1):

Maven's `src/main/resources` directory is a build time path, not a runtime path.

If you're building a jar file, then everything in `src/main/resources` is copied to the root of the jar.

If you're building a war file, then everything in `src/main/resources` is copied to the root of the /WEB-INF/classes directory in the war.

Now, your JDBC URL `jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/database/dashboard` is indicating a file with a relative path. At runtime this path is relative to the current working directory - and it's unlikely to exist at runtime anyway.

If you really want to build the database within your WAR, then given:

- you're deploying an exploded WAR file (it's impossible to write to the content of the WAR file itself);
- you really really want to store the database within the exploded WAR;
- you want to put it in `WEB-INF/database/dashboard` (there's security implications if you store outside of the WEB-INF directory);

then you can compute the JDBC url using something like:

```
...
String databaseDirectoryName = servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/database");
File databaseDirectory = new File(databaseDirectoryName);
if (!databaseDirectory.exists()) {
    if (!databaseDirectory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create database directory");
    }
}
File databaseFile = new File(databaseDirectory, "dashboard");
String jdbcURL = "jdbc:hsqldb:" + databaseFile.toURI();
...
```

Getting that into your Spring configuration is an exercise for you; but using `@Configuration` and `@Bean` springs to mind as a way to do this - you just need to get access to the `servletContext` at Spring configuration time.